# WS Security verification : SignedXml.CheckSignature always returns false even for a correct SOAP message

Tags: c#-4.0, biztalk

Thanks in advance.

I am struggling since many days.

1. When I create SignedXML with my own code and try to validate it . It's working fine but when I am getting the SOAP message from other party (which is  working perfect with other JAVA plaftform we have verified.) SignedXml.CheckSignature always giving false result. I tried many options (including reflector for checking source code for SignedXML) but coudn't get any clue.
2. Following is the format of SOAP message with WS-Security which I need to verify (without using WCF framework).

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="CertId-11465961">MIID+jCCAuKgAwIBAgICBrowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwPzELMAkGA1UEBhMCU0UxEjAQBgNVBAoTCVN0ZXJpYSBBQjEcMBoGA1UEAxMTU3RlcmlhIEFCIEVJRCBDQSB2MjAeFw0xMzA1MTMxMTE1MDdaFw0xNTA3MTMxMDMwMDNaMGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlNFMRwwGgYDVQQKFBNM5G5zZvZyc+RrcmluZ2FyIEFCMRMwEQYDVQQLEwo1NTY1NDk3MDIwMSMwDAYDVQQDEwVMRkxpdjATBgNVBAUTDDE2NTU2NTQ5NzAyMDCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAumKsk/yZOfi9886w4GmTcCLdF9YE2Y97vB8Db77ifzABW3ovK3n+yC7ZI626j85hu9Elh08winNPXm9Tv6yU9PuOal18rwIHLer8zvcYgAmSCj7ND+dVezkOKSmNi6ZUGkk0vYaY6rD1bb+YOofcDnDy3TUlMwK8Ml3U9QR/VKsCAwEAAaOCAVwwggFYMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFJCAgCvzWv1A2zP4Uyk8pNbR7osoMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSL1qEqD6UDpPsfDRw/UQ3NkyMYJDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBkAwIwYDVR0RBBwwGoEYc3Nla0BsYW5zZm9yc2FrcmluZ2FyLnNlMBUGA1UdIAQOMAwwCgYIKoVwNgkCDQEwgZUGA1UdHwSBjTCBijBDoEGgP4Y9aHR0cDovL2NkcDIuc3RlcmlhLnNlL2NkcC9laWQvU3RlcmlhJTIwQUIlMjBFSUQlMjBDQSUyMHYyLmNybDBDoEGgP4Y9aHR0cDovL2NkcDEuc3RlcmlhLnNlL2NkcC9laWQvU3RlcmlhJTIwQUIlMjBFSUQlMjBDQSUyMHYyLmNybDAyBggrBgEFBQcBAQQmMCQwIgYIKwYBBQUHMAGGFmh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnN0ZXJpYS5zZS8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAGxhYvom44znVwgNWXZDnklcotlSAPo17C47aMJq9NylMXHSLqYhfjUwRL7Ig6K128StiBhMLG8KbLXE0hgUIEmT/+NYUnlWozC621fxZXIk8sjTFWfcECkXQ1B7sIEYHBiOHlJHyvYINQIetLZgLPzaO4wu2/HWvO/TfXRb0KK4Omix1733YswCylM0ZoZr+meZAmMVTdXkKwSLDw1+xa6IYLTPWNDcl1Ox0lkyYLraVw5R3ihZFLwvn6MApm0OXfuX8dOGiGpXvi8ejwp39Txy9RsBPUYsJcKXW+YQ8Vh9QqF/7Oizy3IW9tzb3IHm6ZYs8C5hH1BVmo4A2Ga8hBs=</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-533766178">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
            <ds:DigestValue>9rVto1vy/hNACyla+vwnJIGExJk=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-968960127">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
            <ds:DigestValue>T1jD9YbuXbf3l65Abuf9Xw8f6fE=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-944359288">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
            <ds:DigestValue>O9rnP0RRV2Dcy70SRRmU1A7lqB4=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          HACu8a2cc3fm2VDE7ri1vCSeT8ozENo0//BJTAt4RiNQYKxIeka1kWAMZHeHOhRu7V9rnNF+zlLt
          /4fOnaMzEhruRQIJG/DCgUACnb070Mh2fwquAqFOsdpH98kc9We5tHYwfnDufoV8mZozomQ5ex2P
          flcE25QjymvXodg5pP0=
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-1977405101">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STRId-1938095182">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-11465961" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"></wsse:Reference>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-968960127">
        <wsu:Created>2015-06-23T11:15:32.012Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2015-06-23T11:51:32.012Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
    <ssek:SSEK xmlns:ssek="http://schemas.ssek.org/ssek/2006-05-10/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-944359288" ssek:AsynchMethod="AsynchPush" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <ssek:SenderId ssek:Type="CN">XXXX</ssek:SenderId>
      <ssek:ReceiverId ssek:Type="CN">XXXX</ssek:ReceiverId>
      <ssek:TxId>deadbeef-9a71-41ca-af2d-a7a333006de8</ssek:TxId>
    </ssek:SSEK>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-533766178">
    <testOk xmlns="urn:SSEKTestOk" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <hello>KUNDAN test</hello>
    </testOk>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

3. Following is the code which I written.

   using System;
   using System.Security.Cryptography;
   using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
   using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Xml;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

   namespace VerifyOnlySignature
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {

   ```
           string Certificate = "CN=KundanKServer";
           XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

           xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false;
           xmlDocument.Load(@"D:\kundan\RnD\BizTalkSSEK_POC\VarifySignature\SampleFiles\BizTalk_SSEK_Out_S_and_P.xml");
           X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateBySubject(Certificate);
           SignedXmlWithId signedXml = new SignedXmlWithId(xmlDocument);
           XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature", SignedXmlWithId.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
           signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);
           signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXmlWithId.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
           bool resultSign = signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true);
           Console.WriteLine(resultSign.ToString());
           Console.ReadKey();
       }

       public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateBySubject(string CertificateSubject)
       {
           if (null == CertificateSubject)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("CertificateSubject");
           X509Certificate2 cert = null;
           X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
           try
           {
               store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
               // Get the certs from the store.
               X509Certificate2Collection CertCol = store.Certificates;

               // Find the certificate with the specified subject. 
               foreach (X509Certificate2 c in CertCol)
               {
                   if (c.Subject == CertificateSubject)
                   {
                       cert = c;
                       break;
                   }
               }

               // Throw an exception of the certificate was not found. 
               if (cert == null)
               {
                   throw new CryptographicException("The certificate could not be found.");
               }
           }
           finally
           {
               // Close the store even if an exception was thrown.
               store.Close();
           }

           return cert;
       }
   }

   public class SignedXmlWithId : SignedXml
   {



       public SignedXmlWithId(XmlDocument xml)
           : base(xml)
       {
       }

       public SignedXmlWithId(XmlElement xmlElement)
           : base(xmlElement)
       {
       }

       public override XmlElement GetIdElement(XmlDocument doc, string id)
       {
           // check to see if it's a standard ID reference
           XmlElement idElem = base.GetIdElement(doc, id);

           if (idElem == null)
           {
               XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
               nsManager.AddNamespace("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

               idElem = doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@wsu:Id=\"" + id + "\"]", nsManager) as XmlElement;

           }

           return idElem;

       }



   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Are you saying the same method produces different results on exactly the same message?  Are there any difference between the message it works fine on and the message it doesn't?  Particularly with regard to namespaces, use of prefixes or not?  Are you sure the certificates are the same in both environments?

Comment: No, Both message are different.

Comment: 1.We are going to replace a platform, On old platform incoming message some other party ar successfully getting validated (JAVA platform). No we replaced the platform to microsoft (for which i wrote above code) which couldn't validte the same message.

Comment: 2. But whenever I am signing the soap message by my code which is getting validated successfully by this.

Comment: You need to compare the two messages then.  And you need to test on the real message, not one you've generated

Comment: Following is the SignedXML logs. It is failing while verifying SignedInfo. Comparing the Hash value with Signature (I verified from Reflector)

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 12 : [SignedXmlWithId#00c750ce, VerificationFailure] Verification failed checking SignedInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,
Its working fine now.

Issue: put below line

1. Xmldoc.PreserveWhitespace = true
2. Don't format the xml document, keep it as it is .

Regards

Kundan